# Don't GET req.query.name to collection.find in express and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, monk

I use a mongodb database where I have its internal log data.
With Express, Node and Monk (following [this](https://closebrace.com/tutorials/2017-03-02/the-dead-simple-step-by-step-guide-for-front-end-developers-to-getting-up-and-running-with-nodejs-express-and-mongodb) guide) I have to try to get data from a search text box, and I stopped on how to request this data.

from the userlist.ejs page I have implemented a form where I send a GET request:

```
http://localhost:3000/userlist?name=5044
```

where then I go to get name through

```
search = req.query.name
```

and then insert it into the **collection.find({search}.....**

below is the index.js:

```
/* GET Userlist page. */
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {

    search = req.query.name;

    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('startup_log');
    collection.find({search},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', {
          "userlist" : docs
    });
});
```

});

this is the userlist.ejs page where I send the request. which later should display it through the for loop after processing it from index.ejs,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>User List</title>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
   </head>
 <body>
     <h1>User List</h1>

     <input type="text" id="titles" />

<form action="/userlist" method="GET" encType="multipart/form-data">
  <label htmlFor="newNote">New Note:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"  className="form-control" rows="5" 
     id="name" placeholder="5044"></input>
    <button id="done" type="submit" className="btn btn-primary pull- 
     right">Done</button>
    <button id="cancel" className="btn btn-warning pull- 
   right">Cancel</button>
</form>

 <ul>
    <% for (var i = 0; i < userlist.length; i++) {%>
 
    <li><%= userlist[i].hostname %></li>
     
        <li></li>        
     <%}%>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

i can't figure out how to pass to collection.find the query i enter in the text box!
any help would be appreciated as I cannot find specific information about my case.
Thanks in advance!

> UPDATE

I can say that I have tried them all, I am about to give up!
I also tried with an if else, I tried to change the field, but nothing, it does not take the damn

```
let query = req.query.name;
```

from:

```
http://localhost:3000/search?name=5044
```

the funny thing is that it works perfectly well in this way:

```
router.get('/search', async (req, res)=> {

if (!req.query.name)
return res.render("search", {
  title: "NodeMongo Search",
  userlist:[],
});

else {
  const url = 'localhost:27017/local'; // Connection URL
  const db = require('monk')(url);
  const collection = db.get('startup_log')
  try{
    
let query = 5044; //assigning the pid directly to the variable query
const userlist = await collection.find({pid:query});
res.render("search",{userlist});
  }catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}}
});
```

so assigning 5044 to the query variable run perfectly, but:

```
router.get('/search', async (req, res)=> {

if (!req.query.name)
return res.render("search", {
  title: "NodeMongo Search",
  userlist:[],
});

else {
  const url = 'localhost:27017/local'; // Connection URL
  const db = require('monk')(url);
  const collection = db.get('startup_log')
  try{
    
let query = req.query.name;
const userlist = await collection.find({pid:query});
res.render("search",{userlist});
  }catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}}
});
```

assigning the query **req.query.name** NO

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is done correctly, except for the actual MongoDB query. `{search}` expands to `{search: search}` so it will search inside a field called `search` in your database and I'm assuming no such field exists.

You can read about the correct MongoDB query syntax here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

For example, to return only documents where the field `email` would equal your search query, you'd use `{email: search}`. I can't give you an exact solution for your case though because you didn't show the structure of your database documents.

Comment: search is just a variable! unfortunately it is conceptually correct, but it does not pass it to the ejs page. I think the GET request is made before the clik event and therefore the value in the ejs page is empty

Comment: ie the ejs page is immediately called up with the text box value still empty, when I execute a request I should call index.js, but I can't do it!

Comment: No, it's not just a variable. As I said, `{ xyz }` in JavaScript is the same as `{ xyz: xyz }`, i.e. you get an object with one property **whose name is actually `xyz`** and whose value is set by the contents of the `xyz` variable! So your server-side code is executed just fine, but the MongoDB query will deliver zero results because you are searching in a non-existing database field called `search` so no documents will ever match...

Comment: thanks for the answer, I added changed search with the field that I have to search, but still same problem !!!!

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in the solution, it is that **req.query** only passes strings, so I solved it in this way;

```
var query = (+req.query.name);
```

Other ideas would be well accepted !