# Pass after click event in ejs page the result of the req.query.name request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I would need to pass after a `click` event in an ejs page the result of the `req.query.name` request to the `router.get` in `index.js`

```
router.get('/log', function (req, res) { //what i would like to do is: router.get('/req.query.name', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var pid = req.query.name;
    var collection = db.get('startup_log');
    
    collection.find({ pid }, function (e, docs) {
        res.render('userlist', { userlist: docs });
        console.log(pid);
```

The request must be sent only after clicking on the search criteria

below the form of the ejs page:

```
<form action="/log" method="GET" encType="multipart/form-data">
    <label htmlFor="newNote">New Note:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" className="form-control" rows="5" id="name" placeholder="text here"></input>
    <button id="done" type="submit" className="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="x"></button>Done</button>
    <button id="cancel" className="btn btn-warning pull-right">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

thanks for who will help me !!!

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear what you are asking. The code already receives the `name` field in the query string. Please give a concrete example of you what want to the result to look like and what currently happens instead.

Comment: basically I want to call the buttonclick event and send the text req.query in the collection.find, then look for the query in the database

Comment: This is what you already doing (there is also an unnecessary `onclick` but the form should get submitted even with this error), what's the problem?

Comment: ok sorry if unclear, I link you the complete question that I have not received an answer, thanks!   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66338404/problem-to-query-mongodb-through-collection-find-from-simple-text-box-in-browser

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions...

Comment: it is true since I had not obtained an answer I was dissecting the problem ....

Comment: See my answer on the other question, I think your issue is that you aren't querying the database correctly. In the example you showed here, you are searching for a field called `pid` in your database for example, and probably that's not what you wanted.